# Does Datadog tracing impact performance? (specifically Node.js)

Tags: node.js, trace, datadog

Does using Datadog tracing to monitor the performance of my Express (Node.js) REST API impact the throughput (requests per second)? In in other words, is there any performance overhead with tracing requests?

If so, what would the reduction in throughput be? (e.g. -10% approx.)

Comment: Of course there will be some overhead, because the server needs to do more work. You would need to measure how much in your actual use case.